What is your preferred place to ask for help about Godot?
I’m currently exploring different platforms for Godot-related discussions and I’m interested in your preferences. Do you usually turn to the official Godot forums, the Godot subreddit, gamedev.stackexchange.com, or Discord when you need help or advice about Godot?
Additionally, could you share your experiences regarding the community atmosphere on these platforms? Is it generally friendly? Are the responses you receive typically helpful?

Great question, however it is opinion-based in its current format.  Can you edit it so that is asking about the differences between the sites in a more objective manner, please?

Or, if you'd like to poll for personal opinions/experiences, this could be a good topic to discuss in [chat].

This meta-site is about asking how to improve gamedev.stackexchange.com. Discussionas about  other websites are off-topic here, imo.
